# Java loads the method, but Maven can't see it

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, methods, highlight

IntelliJ highlights the getFirstName method as it is wrong. However, everything works and compiles. What can I do to make Maven see this method as well?

[image: highlight]

[image: class]

Comment: Idea doesn't see the getter generated by lombok, does it?  Have you installed the lombok plugin? If not, give it a shot: [Idea Lombok Plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6317-lombok/)

Comment: You can easily __[embed the image](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)__ into you post by prefixing the link with an exclamation-mark, for example: `![Image description][6]`. So we can see it directly :-)

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comments. I am new but I will try better next time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If everything works and compiles it might not be from Maven. Sometimes IntelliJ gets confused. 
If you haven't done this I'd suggest you to [File | Invalidate Caches/Restart](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Cleaning_System_Cache.html)

Hope it helps.

**Edit :** As [Petr Aleksandrov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5990117/petr-aleksandrov) commented, you can check the Jidea Annotation processor : [Configuring Annotation Processing](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-annotation-processing.html)

Comment: Thank you Petr! This plugin Lombok helped solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

sometime the modules are not set properly  in "project structure->project settings->modules" and there intelliJ can resolve the class.

is it a maven project? re-importing it could help.

and you use lombok right? intall the lombok-plugin if you haven't